# Convert rgba into separate properties in CSS

Tags: css, opacity

How can separate rgba into separate properties - colour and opacity.

Ie. `rgba(255,255,255,0.5);`

would be

```
rgba(255,255,255);
```

and

```
opacity(0.5);
```

Is this possible in CSS?

PS. I do need it to have the same effect as rgba, ie. transparent background, not the whole element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make sure you add the browser tags for cross browser compatibility for opacity.

`-ms-, -web-kit-, -o-, -moz-`

`.someElement {
      background-color: rgb(255,255,255); 
      opacity: 0.5; 
    }`

After re-reading.  If you want only the background transparent, you must use `rgba(255,255,255,0.5);` to avoid giving opacity to the element's child elements.

Comment: wrong unfortunately. This is will affect the whole element not just the background of the element.

Comment: Your question is a little misleading and it is possible.  You just need to apply it to the element with the transparent background.  A little clarity or `html/css` would be helpful in assisting you.

Comment: @benhowdle89  rgba(); is a only property which create the background color transparent & not effect his child elements.